# Process.CommandLine gives two different results in powershell

Tags: powershell, split, win32-process

This seems like this should be really straightforward but I cannot seem to find the way to it.

**Code**

```
$processName = "notepad.exe"
$filter = "name like '%"+$processName+"'"
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter
$res = $result.CommandLine
$res
```

Now when I run the above code, I get 2 different output for **$res** when I have a different file open in Notepad. So why does it give me 2 different results?

**Output**

```
"notepad.exe" full_file_path    

"C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" full_file_path
```

When I split the `$res` output by space using the following code

```
$r = $res.Split("",2)
$r1 = $r[0]
$r2 = $r[1]
```

I get

**$r**

```
"C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE"
full_file_path
```

**$r1**

```
"C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE"
```

**$r2**

```
full_file_path
```

Now to get the folder where Notepad is located using Split-Path,

```
Split-Path $r1
```

I get

```
"C:\Windows\system32
```

instead of

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

But when I run

```
Split-Path "C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE"
```

I get `C:\Windows\system32`. So why does `Split-Path` when passed a variable as argument give `"C:\Windows\system32`

Comment: What is your actual question? The code you posted does not generate any output at all. (Everything is assigned to variables.) Also, if you want to use split-path on a quoted string, you have to get rid of the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable, which is a string, contains embedded quotes and that throws off Split-Path e.g.:

```
$p = '"C:\temp"'
$p
Split-Path $p
```

Outputs:

```
"C:\temp"
"C:\
```

Try this to eliminate the quotes:

```
$r1 = $r1.Trim('"')
Split-Path $r1
```

This outputs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves a part of my question. The other question is: I get the full path to the notepad application as the output for `$res` when I have some file open and I get `notepad.exe` for others. Why?

Comment: I'm running V5 preview and it gives the full path in both cases.  When I get a chance I'll try on some V4 machines.  What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: I'm running Powershell v4. I'm running the code using Powershell ISE on Windows 7 32-bit.